# imagejpeg not saving image to folder

Tags: php, image, crop, jcrop

I'm using this PHP code :

```
$targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
                $jpeg_quality = 100;

                $src = $_POST['img'];
                $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
                $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

                $finalName = mt_rand().'_'.mt_rand().'_'.mt_rand().'.jpg';

                imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],
                $targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

                header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
                //imagejpeg($dst_r, "uploads/avatars/" . $finalName, $jpeg_quality);

                imagejpeg($dst_r, null, $jpeg_quality);
```

When I'm using :

```
imagejpeg($dst_r, null, $jpeg_quality);
```

it's working without any problem.

When I'm using this one to save image to folder :

```
imagejpeg($dst_r, "uploads/avatars/" . $finalName, $jpeg_quality);
```

It's not working.
the folder `avatars` has 755 permission so it's not permission problem.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: use try catch block and post the exception message if any.. It may be a problem due to ownership too. Hard to tell like this.

Comment: @noc2spam Thank you very much for your help, I tried to use `try` and I didn't get any error message but I'm getting black image. Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Try chown-ing the folder. login via SSH and run `sudo -i`.. go to the folder and run `chown -Rv apache:apache *` ( considering that your www user is `apache`.) and try again. If ownership is incorrect, file permission won't work anyway.